# saving a set of arrays from python output to csv file

Tags: python, numpy

```
for tstep in arange (1,500,1):
    Intensity=np.sum(Itarray*detarray)
    print tstep*t*10**9, "\t", Intensity.real
```

For the above program how do I save the two arrays tstep*t*10**9 and Intensity.real into a csv file as two colums with a tab so that I get all the values as the loop goes from 1 to 500

Comment: What is the actual question? How to save the result to file instead of printing it? Also, your question is tagged `python-3.x` while the code is Python 2.x code.

Comment: yes I want to save the output in csv file. Yes the code is in Python 2.x code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, it's as simple as;

```
myfile = open("test.out", "w")

for tstep in arange (1,500,1):
    Intensity=np.sum(Itarray*detarray)
    myfile.write(str(tstep*t*10**9) + '\t' + str(Intensity.real) + '\n')

myfile.close()
```

Comment: this doesn't work. It only writes the first value of tstep*t*10**9 and 500 values of Intensity.real in the same line separated by a tab

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a for-loop, use

```
tsteps = np.arange(1,500,1, dtype='int64')*t*10**9
```

to build a NumPy array. Note carefully that NumPy arrays have a dtype. The dtype determines the range of numbers representable by the elements in the array. For example, with dtype `int64`, an array can represent all integers between

```
In [35]: np.iinfo('int64').min, np.iinfo('int64').max
Out[35]: (-9223372036854775808L, 9223372036854775807L)
```

For the sake of speed, NumPy does not check for arithmetic overflow. 
If `499*t*10**9` falls outside this range, then the array will contain wrong numbers. So the onus is on you to choose the right dtype to avoid arithmetic overflow.

Note also that if `t` is a float, then `np.arange(1,500,1, dtype='int64')*t` will get upcasted to dtype `float64`, whose range of representable values lie between

```
In [34]: np.finfo('float64').min, np.finfo('float64').max
Out[34]: (-1.7976931348623157e+308, 1.7976931348623157e+308)
```

---

`np.sum(Itarray*detarray)` does not depend on `tstep`, so it can be pulled outside the `for-loop`. Or, since we are not using a `for-loop`, it just needs to be computed once.

---

Finally, form a 2D array (using [np.column_stack](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html)), and save it to a file with [np.savetxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html):

```
import numpy as np
tsteps = np.arange(1,500,1, dtype='int64')*t*10**9
Intensity = np.sum(Itarray*detarray)
np.savetxt(filename, np.column_stack(tsteps, Intensity.real), delimiter='\t')
```

Comment: yes but both Itarray and detarray has tsteps inside it. In that case how can the program be modified?

Comment: One of the beautiful aspects of NumPy is that [arithmetic operations apply elementwise](http://wiki.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial#head-4c1d53fe504adc97baf27b65513b4b97586a4fc5). So you may be able to write down equations for `Itarray` and `detarray` in terms of `tsteps`. For more specific advice, you'll need to explain how `Itarray` and `detarray` are defined.

Comment: Notice, in fact, that we are taking advantage of the fact that arithmetic operations apply elementwise to define `tsteps` itself. `np.arange(...)` is a NumPy array, and we the multiply it by a scalar, `t*10**9`. The result is the same as if we multiplied each element in the array by the scalar amount in a `for-loop`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `csv` module. Your question is a little bit unclear. I am assuming that `Intensity` is an array with 500 entries.

```
Intensity = np.sum(Itarray*detarray)
w = csv.writer(open('output.csv','w'), delimiter='\t')
w.writerows([('%e' % ((i+1)*t*10**9),'%f' % b) for i,b in enumerate(Intensity.real)])
```

Comment: how is the shape of your `Intensity` array?

Comment: Intensity.real is an array of 500 values within 0.1 and 1.0

Comment: I've updated the answer... this should work given that `Intensity.real` is an `1D-array`